# Lisp Sum of power

Tags: lisp

Define a function "power" that takes two input arguments m and n, and returns m^n. Then, by using the function "power", define a function sum_power that takes two input arguments m and n and returns the sum: (1^n + 2^n + 3^n +.... + m^n).

int first function i calculate power from given arguments in second function a sum powers. But program gives error: Program stack overflow. RESET...
I cant find my error. Function power is correct I checked.

```
(defun power(m n)
  (let ((result 1))
    (dotimes (count n result)
      (setf result (* m result)))))

(defun sum_power (m n)
  (if (= 0 m)
      0
      (+ (powern m) 
         (sum_power (1- m) n))))
```

Comment: This code is hard to read. You need to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is your function sum_power when you pass the variable m 
the expression `(- 1 m)` is an infinite loop first time because is for example

> for m =  5 first time (- 1 m) => -4 (new m = -4) second time (- 1 m)
>   => 5 (new m = 5)

begin again so is a recusive infinite loop, you never arrive to 1 so this is teh case of the overflow

Use instead the build function `(1- m)` which decreases the value of m, or `(- m 1)` if you want

So the new funtion will be like this, also this is no tail recursion so for big m and n it will take a lot of time, but for your needs it should work, and this function is better formated, please take of fromatting when writing lisp functions for easy reading

```
(defun sum_power (m n)
  (if (= 1 m)
      1
      (+ (power n m) (sum_power (1- m) n))
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have done so dumb mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a argument order mistake in your sum_power function. The stand lisp function `-` when given two arguments subtracts the second argument from the first argument that is `(- 1 m)` will subtract m from one and NOT 1 from m as you probably expected thus your result will be a negative integer and your base case `(= 1 m)` will never be reached. For you code to work correctly you have to swap the arguments to `-` thus `(- m 1)` or you can user the lisp function `1-` `(1- m)` which subtracts one from its only argument thus a corrected version of your code is as follows:

```
(defun sum_power (m n)
   (if (= 1 m)
       1
       (+ (power m n) (sum_power (1- m) n))))
```

On a non-related side-note lisp allows a lot more characters in function, variable and macro names than most other languages thus you can use sum-power instead of sum_power, in-fact it is arguably better lisp style to use hyphens to join multiple-word identifier names rather than underscores (as used in C) or camel-back casing (sumPower as used in Java). Secondly closing parenthesis usually are not written on a separate line but are on the same line as the last expression before the closing parentheses, as I have done above in the corrected version. These are merely conventions you may follow them if you wish but you're not obliged to.

Comment: I'm new to Lisp, after OO languages it's hard to get used it. TY for your advice and information.

Comment: I recommend Practical Common Lisp as a guide, http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/ it teaches most of Common Lisp's functionality at least that which is most used. By the way Lisp supports OO programming.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use higher-order functions and loop macro? I think is more readable that way:

```
(defun power (n m)
   (reduce #'* (loop for x below n collect m))

(defun sum-power (n m)
   (reduce #'+ (loop for x from 1 to m collect (power x n)))
```